# How can I get parent, grandparent and grandgrand parent keys of one array key in a multidimensional array?

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

This is my array:

```
array(1) {
  ["farm"]=>
  array(2) {
    ["folder1"]=>
    array(2) {
      ["horse"]=>
      array(1) {
        ["fred"]=>
        string(4) "fred"
      }
      ["cat"]=>
      array(1) {
        ["john"]=>
        string(4) "john"
      }
    }
    ["folder2"]=>
    array(1) {
      ["cat"]=>
      array(2) {
        ["sam"]=>
        string(3) "sam"
        ["cat"]=>
        array(1) {
          ["john"]=>
          string(4) "john"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

This is my function:

```
    $search = "folder1";
    get_values($arr);

   function get_values($arr, $id){  
        global $search;
        foreach($arr as $key => $value){

            if($key == $search){

                if(is_array($value)){

                    foreach( $value as $k => $v ) {
                        echo $k;
                    }   
                }           
            }else{
                get_values($value, $id ); 
            }      
        }      
    }
```

My result:

```
horse
cat
```

What I need not only the array key. I also want to print all parents (parent, grandparent until the root) keys.
The result I would need:

```
farm/folder1/horse
farm/folder1/cat
```

As far as I could get is this. But here I get only the parent not the grand and grandgrand parents:

```
  foreach( $value as $k => $v ) {
       echo $key."/".$k;
  }
```

The result is

```
folder1/horse
folder1/cat
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add a path argument to your function.

```
$search = "folder1";
get_values($arr, null);

function get_values($arr, $path, $id){  
    global $search;
    foreach($arr as $key => $value){
        $basePath = $path === null ? $key : $path. "/" . $key;
        if($key == $search){

            if(is_array($value)){

                foreach( $value as $k => $v ) {
                    echo $basePath . '/' . $k;
                }   
            }           
        }else{
            get_values($value, $basePath, $id); 
        }      
    }      
}
```

Comment: Yes this looks working! Thank you :) Just one issue: With your function my result is `1234/farm/folder1/horse` so somehow the `id` went to the beginning of the path. I tried to remove `$id` from your function, but strangely it is still there

Comment: the issue is probably in the surrounding code, the $id in this function is actually never used, I did not edit it out from your code

Comment: It was how I executed the function, my mistake! So actually everything is fine! :)